# What do "and" means infront of a variable?

Tags: plugin-development

When we use `&` in argument in function it means if we change the variable inside that function the variable will be not be changed outside.

```
<?php
function add_10(&$number)
{
    $number +=10;
}
$our_lovely_number = 10;
add_10($our_lovely_number);
echo $our_lovely_number;    // outputs 20 
?>
```

isn't it ?

But when I came across plugins I saw that `&` was used inside contructor function. What does it means ?

Like this

```
//this is constructor function
add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'adminInit'));
```

I tried to search google by "what do and means in wordpress hooks", but I see nothing

Comment: `&` is a reference, they should generally be avoided, and are in almost all cases unnecessary

Comment: @TomJNowell yes but i found many popular plugin using that in wordpress action hooks ? is there any reason?

Comment: also note that `&$this` in action and filter registrations is a PHP4-ism, not modern PHP5 code. You should never put `&$this` when writing code, it's a holdover from the days WP supported PHP4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you are simply creating an array `array(&$this, 'adminInit')` where `array[0]` now references whatever `$this` is, and `array[1] = 'adminInit'`.

I believe in this case `$this` references the class you're in ( denoted by &$this ) and then `adminInit` is likely a function (method) within that class. 
Therefore when the `admin_init` happens it knows to access the `adminInit()` function in the current class you're in.

& preceding a variable means it's a reference (pointer) to this variable and not the actual value. Of course it will still return the value when called but it does it sort of like a shortcut would to open file. Here's an example to help you understand.

```
$variable1 = "one"; //set $variable1
$variable2 = &$variable1; //make $variable2 reference $variable1

echo $variable1; //echos "one"
echo "<br>";
echo $variable2; //echos "one"
echo "<hr>";

$variable1 = "two"; //only change the value of $variable1

echo $variable1; //echos "two"
echo "<br>";
echo $variable2; //echos "two"
echo "<hr>";

$variable2 = "three"; //only change the value of $variable2 (which is actually $variable1 by reference)

echo $variable1; //echos "three"
echo "<br>";
echo $variable2; //echos "three"
echo "<hr>";
```

Another way to understand it would be like...

```
function change_reference( &$ref ){
        $ref = "two";
}

$var1 = "one";

change_reference( $var1 );

echo $var1; //will echo "two"
```

You can start here http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php and then use the References Explained menu links to dig deeper.

Comment: Yes thank you but what do they mean in wordpress hook?

Comment: I rewrote my answer to try to clarify what's happening for you. & is core php and not WordPress specific. The hook simply needs to know what function to access and what class to access it in and the array holds the class and the function to call within that class.

Comment: yes nice :) very clean and good answer :)